# G++: linker doesnt seem to link correctly

Tags: linux, linker, g++

I try to compile a program I have to control a DAQ device. In Windows, g++ compile and links OK, but in Linux it doesn't. The linker (called by G++) displays:

```
g++ -Wall -o "acelerar-30-0" "acelerar-30-0.cpp" (en el directorio: /home/poly/)
/tmp/ccRLpB4q.o: In function `main':
acelerar-30-0.cpp:(.text+0x429): undefined reference to `AdxInstantAoCtrlCreate'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Ha fallado la compilación.
```

The cpp file is this (cut):

```
include stdlib.h
include stdio.h
include math.h
include "compatibility.h"
include "bdaqctrl.h"
include "comunes.h"
using namespace Automation::BDaq;
define deviceDescription L"USB-4704,BID#0"
int32       channelStart = 0;
int32       channelCount = 1;
double      voltaje[0];
int32       modo;
int32       ms;
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc!=3)
        salidaerror(argv[0],1);
    channelStart = atoi(argv[1]);
    ms = atoi(argv[2]);
    if (channelStart<0||channelStart>1||ms<10)
        salidaerror(argv[0],1);
    ErrorCode ret = Success;
    InstantAoCtrl * instantAoCtrl = AdxInstantAoCtrlCreate();
...
```

I have been several hours on this, and can't find the answer. The SDK is for Debian/Ubuntu, and it has the same code for Linux and Windows.

Any hints? Thanks

EDIT: Removed some marks as the formatting was incorrect

Comment: where is `AdxInstantAoCtrlCreate()` defined?

Comment: in the file bdaqctrl.h. The file has this: InstantAoCtrl* AdxInstantAoCtrlCreate(); and: __inline InstantAoCtrl* AdxInstantAoCtrlCreate()   

   {

      return (InstantAoCtrl*)BDaqObjectCreate("AdxInstantAoCtrlCreate");

   } with a lot if things... i can upload the file if you want

Comment: You should probably post the part that's relevant, yes...

Comment: http://pastebin.com/e1wZu1Em that's the bdaqctrl.h

Comment: That header _declares_ the function, it doesn't _define_ it - you need to link to the library defining it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my (limited) experience, typical gcc behavior will require that you specify the library containing that function as an argument on the command line like so:

```
-lsome_library
```

This is required even if the library is in your library path (additional library paths can be specified with -L). Find the appropriate library file containing that function and use its filename minus extensions and leading "lib" in the argument format above.

Comment: You're right: I have found the library, so still can't link it. It is in /usr/lib and it's called libbiodaq.so , so I attach to the end of the g++ argument: -llibbiodaq with no success :( still looking for it